# How to handle users data in an aws-based serverless stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm a first-timer with AWS and I'm a bit lost. 
I would like to have a serverless stack using Cognito to handle authentication, DynamoDB, Lambda and CloudFront for exposing REST services.

I don't know exactly how to handle users data. For example, I would like to store the user email and physical address. I've seen you can have that directly in Cognito, however, I would like to perform custom validation when these attributes are set/updated.

Can I do that easily with a trigger, letting the user have a Write access on its data?

Or should I restrain Write access to these attributes and expose a REST service to update them manually in a lambda?

I've also seen someone using a users table in DynamoDB to store some data, what are the advantage compared to using directly the identity pool?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store this kind of data(email, address) in Cognito user pools and validate the data using PreSignUp Lambda trigger, [more details](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html).

Comment: But doing that, how can I check data when the user update its informations, there's no trigger for that, is there?

Comment: Unfortunately no, AWS doesn't have a trigger for when Cognito user pool attributes are updated after signup is completed. I've always ended up building a REST service in API Gateway and Lambda to update Cognito.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using DynamoDB to store user data is that you will almost certainly hit a RequestLimitExceeded exception using Cognito as a primary data store. If you contact AWS support and explain what you are doing, they will up the Cognito API limit on your account - but that only temporarily solves the problem. Since Amazon doesn't publish what will trigger a RequestLimitExceeded error, you will eventually hit it again if your traffic increases.

Every time I have tried to use Cognito as the only source of user data I have run into this problem. So I end up storing user data in Dynamo or RDS.

If you don't have a lot of traffic or if you aren't going to be querying the Cognito API often, then it might work for you